# Convert numpy list of lists to a table (variable length)

Tags: python, numpy

The data that I need to convert looks like this:

```
array([(array(['test_00000001.jpg'], dtype='<U17'), array([[2694, 1211,  353,  353,    1,    9,  105,  144,  337,    2,    3,
           2,    2,    1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [1754, 1449,   68,   68,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,
          -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1]], dtype=int16)),
       (array(['test_00000002.jpg'], dtype='<U17'), array([[113,  95, 226, 226,   1,   9,  71, 181, 221,   1,   3,   1,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16)),
       (array(['test_00000003.jpg'], dtype='<U17'), array([[352, 114, 151, 151,   1,  17,  45, 137, 135,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1],
       [799, 217, 139, 139,   2,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
         -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16)),
       ...,
       (array(['test_00004933.jpg'], dtype='<U17'), array([[ 80, 121, 245, 245,   1,  50,  81, 238, 242,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16)),
       (array(['test_00004934.jpg'], dtype='<U17'), array([[148, 266, 276, 276,   1,  38,  68, 265, 248,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16)),
       (array(['test_00004935.jpg'], dtype='<U17'), array([[110,  98, 318, 318,   1,  73, 124, 313, 302,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16))],
      dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('label', 'O')])
```

There are two columns - name and label.
The label column is an array of a variable number of arrays (not more than 20). 
My goal is to split the label column such as that every row contains only one subarray from the original label field.
For example, if the label column looks like this:

```
[[arr1], [arr2]]
[[arr3], [arr4], [arr5]]
```

The result should be

```
[arr1]
[arr2]
[arr3]
[arr4]
[arr5]
```

Comment: Can you show how have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some editing to recreating your array from the sample, but I got:

```
In [388]: A.shape                                                                                      
Out[388]: (6,)
In [389]: A.dtype                                                                                      
Out[389]: dtype([('name', 'O'), ('label', 'O')])
```

That's a 1d array with 2 fields, each with object dtype.  ONe field contains 1d arrays of string dtype:

```
In [390]: A['name']                                                                                    
Out[390]: 
array([array(['test_00000001.jpg'], dtype='<U17'),
       array(['test_00000002.jpg'], dtype='<U17'),
       array(['test_00000003.jpg'], dtype='<U17'),
       array(['test_00004933.jpg'], dtype='<U17'),
       array(['test_00004934.jpg'], dtype='<U17'),
       array(['test_00004935.jpg'], dtype='<U17')], dtype=object)
```

the other contains arrays:

```
In [391]: A['label']                                                                                   
Out[391]: 
array([array([[2694, 1211,  353,  353,    1,    9,  105,  144,  337,    2,    3,
           2,    2,    1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [1754, 1449,   68,   68,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,
          -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1]], dtype=int16),
       array([[113,  95, 226, 226,   1,   9,  71, 181, 221,   1,   3,   1,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16),
       array([[352, 114, 151, 151,   1,  17,  45, 137, 135,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1],
       [799, 217, 139, 139,   2,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,
         -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16),
       array([[ 80, 121, 245, 245,   1,  50,  81, 238, 242,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16),
       array([[148, 266, 276, 276,   1,  38,  68, 265, 248,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16),
       array([[110,  98, 318, 318,   1,  73, 124, 313, 302,   1,   3,   2,   2,
          3,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]], dtype=int16)], dtype=object)
```

checking their shapes:

```
In [392]: [i.shape for i in A['label']]                                                                
Out[392]: [(2, 18), (1, 18), (2, 18), (1, 18), (1, 18), (1, 18)]
```

Given those shapes I could combine them into a 2d array with `vstack`.  That's the only thing possible with the variable first dimension:

```
In [393]: np.vstack(A['label'])                                                                        
Out[393]: 
array([[2694, 1211,  353,  353,    1,    9,  105,  144,  337,    2,    3,
           2,    2,    1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [1754, 1449,   68,   68,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,
          -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [ 113,   95,  226,  226,    1,    9,   71,  181,  221,    1,    3,
           1,    2,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [ 352,  114,  151,  151,    1,   17,   45,  137,  135,    1,    3,
           2,    2,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [ 799,  217,  139,  139,    2,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,
          -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [  80,  121,  245,  245,    1,   50,   81,  238,  242,    1,    3,
           2,    2,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [ 148,  266,  276,  276,    1,   38,   68,  265,  248,    1,    3,
           2,    2,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1],
       [ 110,   98,  318,  318,    1,   73,  124,  313,  302,    1,    3,
           2,    2,    3,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1]], dtype=int16)
In [394]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[394]: (8, 18)
```

The names could be combined into one string array:

```
In [395]: np.hstack(A['name'])                                                                         
Out[395]: 
array(['test_00000001.jpg', 'test_00000002.jpg', 'test_00000003.jpg',
       'test_00004933.jpg', 'test_00004934.jpg', 'test_00004935.jpg'],
      dtype='<U17')
```